# Problema al cargar imagenes de la BD al directorio

Tags: php, mysql, android, phpmyadmin

Actualmente estoy tratando de hacer una app en Android en la cual se muestra en un listado la descripción de los productos y su imagen correspondiente, con conexión de BD mediante PHP. Pero el problema es que al cargar las imágenes de la BD al directorio (en este caso una carpeta en mi computadora), me está dando el error de "Out of memory", adjunto captura de pantalla para que se entienda a que me refiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-La variable max_execution_time dentro del archivo php.ini, lo cambié a 0, es decir tiempo ilimitado, pero eso me terminó dando el error de "out of memory"

-El código en PHP es el siguiente:

```
    <?php
include 'conexion.php';

// Buscar solo las imágenes que aún no tienen archivo
$consulta = "SELECT ip.ImaAsoId, ip.ImaAsoIma, ip.ImaAsoExt, ia.ia_id
        FROM imagenasociada ip
        LEFT JOIN imagenarchivo ia
        ON ip.ImaAsoId = ia.ia_id
        WHERE ia.ia_id IS NULL
        ORDER BY ip.ImaAsoId";
$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);

$ruta = 'img2/';
if($resultado = $conexion->query($consulta)) {
    echo 'Imágenes a modificar: ' . $resultado->num_rows;
    while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        var_dump($fila);
        // Crear archivo con ID de imagen
        $archivo = $fila['ImaAsoId'] . '.' . $fila['ImaAsoExt'];
        file_put_contents($ruta . $archivo, $fila['ImaAsoIma']);
        // Insertar fila en nueva tabla
        $conexion->query("INSERT INTO imagenarchivo SET
        ia_id = {$fila['ImaAsoId']}, ia_archivo = '$archivo'");
    }
}else{
    echo "Error al leer imágenes: ".$conexion->error;
}

?>
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Has mirado los logs de PHP? Es posible que el script se esté deteniendo por superar el tiempo máximo de ejecución, pero es sólo una teoría. Revisa los logs y [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/443037/edit) tu pregunta comentando qué encontraste. Esas variables que modificaste ayudan a que haya más memoria para procesar pero el post size aquí es irrelevante.

Comment: Dentro del log me dió el error de "Maximum execution time of 600 seconds exceeded ", me queda una duda a lo que dijiste ¿la variable post size no era necesario cambiarle el valor?

Comment: Jejeje, TIENES que usar la aproximación que recomienda Triby y ejecutar muchas veces un script que haga menos. Puedes ponerle 1GB al memory_limit, pero eso será siempre una opción menos sabia que cambiar la forma en la que tu código usa los recursos

Comment: @Alfabravo, Edité la pregunta de arriba, porque con la forma que me recomendó Triby me dió problema

Comment: Vale, en un rato intento dar otra idea. Como sugerencia, no desaparezcas lo que habías preguntando antes porque nos pones a borrar la respuesta inicial... :)

Comment: Y de paso hay una aclararción que me gustaría hacer, esta app que estoy haciendo debe estar conectada a un servidor externo, en el cual se cargarían las imagenes en tiempo real, es decir que continuamente habrían nuevas imagenes, por eso es que estoy tratando de solucionar este asunto de las imagenes

Answer (score 1):

Como no puedes modificar tiempo de ejecución ni memoria disponible, seguramente deberás ejecutar varias veces `exportar.php` y, también mencionaste que no puedes modificar la tabla `imagenasociada`, vas a tener que crear otra, probablemente, solo necesites dos campos: ID y nombre de archivo.

**Edición:** De acuerdo a tu [nueva pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/443689/como-asociar-cada-imagen-a-su-producto-correspondiente) es necesario agregar el campo `perid` en la tabla, solo verifica que el tipo de dato es correcto o adáptalo, de acuerdo a la estructura de la tabla `imagenasociada`:

```
CREATE TABLE imagenarchivo (
    ia_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ia_perid int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ia_archivo varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (ia_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

**Importante:** Es necesario que borres esta tabla, la vuelvas a crear y llenar ejecutando nuevamente `exportar.php` las veces que sea necesario.

Tu script `exportar.php` queda así:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

// Buscar solo las imágenes que aún no tienen archivo
$consulta = "SELECT ip.ImaAsoId, ip.perid, ip.ImaAsoIma, ip.ImaAsoExt, ia.ia_id
    FROM imagenasociada ip
    LEFT JOIN imagenarchivo ia
        ON ip.ImaAsoId = ia.ia_id
    WHERE ia.ia_id IS NULL
    ORDER BY ip.ImaAsoId";
$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);

$ruta = 'img2/';
if($resultado = $conexion->query($consulta)) {
    echo 'Imágenes a modificar: ' . $resultado->num_rows;
    while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        var_dump($fila);
        // Crear archivo con ID de imagen
        $archivo = $fila['ImaAsoId'] . '.' . $fila['ImaAsoExt'];
        file_put_contents($ruta . $archivo, $fila['ImaAsoIma']);
        // Insertar fila en nueva tabla
        // Si el campo "perid" no es numérico, enciérralo entre comillas
        $conexion->query("INSERT INTO imagenarchivo SET
            ia_id = {$fila['ImaAsoId']}, ia_perid = {$fila['perid']}, ia_archivo = '$archivo'");
    }
}else{
    echo "Error al leer imágenes: ".$conexion->error;
}
```

Breve explicación de la consulta:

- `SELECT ip.ImaAsoId, ip.ImaAsoIma, ip.ImaAsoExt, ia.ia_id`: Seleccionas los campos necesarios de la tabla original e ID de imagen en tabla que contiene nombre de archivo
- `LEFT JOIN`: Leerá todos los registros que cumplan la condición y, en caso de que no exista en la segunda tabla, asignará `NULL` a los campos especificados
- `WHERE ia.ia_id IS NULL`: Va a filtrar para obtener solo los registros que existen en la tabla original, pero no están aún en la segunda

**Importante:** Vas a tener que ejecutar `exportar.php` varias veces, hasta haber generado todas las imágenes; lo sabrás porque verás el mensaje *"Imágenes a modificar: 0"*. Y, por supuesto, también deberás ejecutarlo cuando se agreguen nuevas imágenes.

Ahora, solo falta que edites la pregunta para ver cómo asocias cada imagen a los productos y saber si los dos campos son suficientes o se necesita algún otro para mostrar la imagen.

Comment: De hecho, dijo que sí pudo modificar php.ini, sólo que cambió lo que no era. Pero me gusta el ejemplo de cómo hacer eso sin que el script se quede ejecutando por siempre.

Comment: Gracias, @Alfabravo, creo que solo "leí por encima". :-D

Comment: @Triby edité la pregunta de arriba, porque ahora me está dando el error de "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::num_rows()"

Comment: Sí, error mío `num_rows` es propiedad y no método, debe quedar así: `echo 'Imágenes a modificar: ' . $resultado->num_rows;`

Comment: @Triby ese error ya lo solucioné, pero el script lo tuve que ejecutar 3 veces dado que eran 1766 imagenes para cargar

Comment: @Triby y eso de como asociar cada imagen a su producto, lo pregunto en una pregunta aparte o cambio la pregunta que tengo más arriba?

Comment: Ya vi que creaste la nueva pregunta. Voy a editar esta respuesta, porque, según vi, se necesita agregar el campo `perid` en la nueva tabla para poder asociar las imágenes fácilmente.

Comment: @StephiRM, actualicé la respuesta y voy a contestar la otra pregunta.

Comment: @Triby , me quedó una duda , ese script para exportar imágenes se debe ejecutar manualmente? Pues mi app está pensada para que los datos queden sincronizados en tiempo real , es decir que si se cambia algo de la BD, también debe actualizarse lo que se muestra en la tablet

Comment: Sí, debes ejecutarlo manualmente, para que el usuario no tenga que esperar a que se generen las nuevas imágenes.

Answer (score 0):

El error que tienes se debe a que tu script tarda mucho tiempo en terminar lo que está haciendo. Escribir mil o más imágenes después de obtenerlas desde la BD es caro en tiempo.

Como lo indicas en tu comentario, el problema es de `max_execution_time`. PHP no deja correr los scripts por siempre y les pone un tiempo máximo en segundos. Ese amigo creo que por defecto viene en 300; si lo necesitas, valdría la pena subirlo de 600 a algo más razonable. Está en el mismo lugar que las otras variables que cambiaste, así que se ajusta igual.

Aunque, si tu proceso tiene cara de tener que procesar más y más imágenes, yo consideraría la posibilidad de no hacer un solo bucle con todo y procesar las imágenes por lotes, ponerles una marca de `isGenerated` e irlas marcando en BD a medida que las exportes como archivo. Algo así

max_post_size aplica para los formularios POST que manipules con PHP, max_upload_size es para esos mismos formularios, cuando sean multipart y lleven archivos adjuntos, memory_limit sí ayuda cuando manipulas conjuntos muy grandes de datos pero el error no se quejó por esto.

Comment: yo en php.ini cambié la variable de max_execution time por 0, que por lo que he investigado, 0 es tiempo ilimitado, eso me cargó todas las imagenes, pero a mi me queda la siguiente pregunta ¿esa solución es óptima o debería probar con otra cosa?

Comment: Quiero aclarar que al hacer este cambio, luego me aparece el error de "out of memory"