# ¿Como asociar cada imagen a su producto correspondiente?

Tags: php, mysql, android

Actualmente estoy tratando de hacer una app en Android en la cual se muestra en un listado la descripción de los productos y su imagen correspondiente, con conexión de BD mediante PHP. Pero el problema es que no me está mostrando la imagen asociada a ese producto.

Mi código para poder listar los productos es el siguiente:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$consulta = "SELECT p.progenid, p.progencod, p.progennom,
        pp.PreProPre1, ip.ImaAsoExt
        FROM productogenerico p 
        INNER JOIN precioproducto pp
        ON p.progenid = pp.proid
        LEFT JOIN imagenasociada ip ON
        p.progenid = ip.perid";

$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
$listado = array();

$ruta = 'http://192.168.43.3/WS/img2/';

while($fila  =$resultado->fetch_array()) {
    $producto["progennom"] = $fila['progennom'];
    $producto["PreProPre1"] = $fila['PreProPre1'];
    $producto["progencod"] = $fila['progencod'];

    $archivo = $fila['progenid'] . '.' . $fila['ImaAsoExt'];

    $producto["ImaAsoIma"] = $ruta . $archivo;
    $listado[] = $producto;
}

echo json_encode($listado);
$resultado->close();
?>
```

Y la tabla imagenarchivo (una que yo agregué) tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
CREATE TABLE imagenarchivo (
ia_id INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
ia_archivo VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (ia_id)
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

¿Como puedo hacer para poder asociar cada imagen a su producto? ¿Y dentro de la tabla imagen archivo, es suficiente esos dos campos o hacen falta más?

Mi código en Android (Java) para poder mostrar la imagen desde la ruta es el siguiente:

Por cierto, cabe aclarar que en mi código uso Glide para poder mostrar la imagen desde la ruta

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher {
private static final String URL_broches = "http://192.168.43.3/WS/listar.php";
ArrayList<Broches> brochesList;
GridView gridView;
EditText editText;
Adapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    brochesList = new ArrayList<>();
    editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    loadBroches();
}

private void loadBroches(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_broches, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("Pruebo1: ", response);
            Broches bro = null;
            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject broche = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    bro = new Broches();
                    bro.setDescripcion(broche.getString("progennom"));
                    bro.setCodigo(broche.getString("progencod"));
                    bro.setPrecio(broche.getDouble("PreProPre1"));
                    bro.setImage(broche.getString("ImaAsoIma"));
                    //bro.setDato(broche.getString("ImaAsoIma"));
                    brochesList.add(bro);
                }
                adapter = new Adapter(brochesList, MainActivity.this);
                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}

public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private List<Broches> brochesList;
    private List<Broches> brochestemp;
    private Context context;

    public Adapter(List<Broches> brochesList, Context context) {
        this.brochesList = brochesList;
        this.brochestemp = brochesList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return brochesList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return brochesList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Broches broches = brochesList.get(position);
        TextView textViewDesc;
        ImageView imageView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
        textViewDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNames);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        if (brochesList.get(position).getImage() != null) {
            Glide.with(context).load(broches.getImage()).into(imageView);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimage);
        }
        textViewDesc.setText(broches.getDescripcion());

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity((new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfoActivity.class).putExtra("broches", brochesList.get(position))));
            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null || constraint.length() > 0) {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                ArrayList<Broches> filters = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < brochestemp.size(); i++) {
                    if (brochestemp.get(i).getDescripcion().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)) {
                        //Broches bro = new Broches(brochestemp.get(i).getDescripcion(), brochestemp.get(i).getCodigo(), brochestemp.get(i).getCodExterno(), brochestemp.get(i).getPrecio(), brochestemp.get(i).getIdproducto(), brochestemp.get(i).getImagen());
                        Broches bro = new Broches(brochestemp.get(i).getDescripcion(), brochestemp.get(i).getCodigo(), brochestemp.get(i).getPrecio(), brochestemp.get(i).getImage());
                        filters.add(bro);
                    }
                }

                filterResults.count = filters.size();
                filterResults.values = filters;

            } else {
                filterResults.count = brochestemp.size();
                filterResults.values = brochestemp;
            }

            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            brochesList = (List<Broches>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

}
```

Comment: ¿Cuántas imágenes puede tener un producto asociadas?

Comment: @BetaM cada producto tiene una imagen asociada

Comment: ¿Para qué sirve la tabla `imagenasociada`  que se ve en tu consulta? Tampoco nos dices qué ocurre con tu código actual ... ¿Funciona mal,arroja datos que no debe arrojar, qué datos por ejemplo...  da error, qué error?

Comment: @BetaM solo una

Comment: @A.Cedano El código que tengo no funciona como debe porque cuando ejecuto mi aplicación, me muestra la descripción del producto, pero no la imagen asociada a ese producto

Comment: Entiendo, pero haz un debug del código en PHP y dinos qué muestra. Tampoco queda claro para qué sirve la tabla `imagenasociada` cuando luego nos muestras otra tabla llamada `imagenarchivo` Y si puedes revisa un poco tu *convencion de nombre*, es complicadísimo en tu consulta SQL saber a qué se refieren las columnas id que usas en los JOIN.

Comment: @A.Cedano en la pregunta de arriba agrgué el código que uso para "exportar" las imagenes, ahi uso la tabla imagenarchivo

Comment: Supongo que ya las imágenes están en las carpetas y que ahora lo que te interesa es obtener la ruta de esas imágenes ¿no? Si es así, ¿en qué tabla están las rutas de las imágenes? Lo de exportar aqui no creo que tenga que ver, son dos cosas diferentes.

Comment: Pusiste la definición de `imagenarchivo`, insertas en `imagenarchivo2` y consultas con `imagenasociada`.

Answer (score 0):

en el ultimo codigo veo que estas exportando a la ruta: **'imagenes2/'**;

y en tu codigo estas buscando en la ruta **/WS/img2/**;

yo creo que sería:

```
$ruta = 'http://192.168.43.3/WS/img2/imagenes2/';
```

o si no:

```
$ruta = 'http://192.168.43.3/WS/imagenes2/';
```

Depende como tengas las carpetas.

Comment: Mala mía en realidad la carpeta es imagenes2

Comment: ok entonces entra a esa ruta http://192.168.43.3/WS/imagenes2/ y te debe de aparecer el listado de imagenes si no te sale entonces busque la ruta correcta, ya cuando tengas la ruta correcta, en el codigo esta esta parte:

$producto["ImaAsoIma"] = $ruta . $archivo;

verifica que $ruta . $archivo exista realmente, puede que falte un slash o algo parecido. 

$ruta . "\\" .$archivo

Answer (score 0):

En tu [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/443037/problema-al-cargar-imagenes-de-la-bd-al-directorio) actualicé la respuesta para agregar la columna con la que asocias imagen con producto, quedando así:

```
CREATE TABLE imagenarchivo (
    ia_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ia_perid int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ia_archivo varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (ia_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

Ahora, para obtener la imagen, vas a usar esta nueva tabla en lugar de `imagenasociada`, solo asegúrate de especificar la misma carpeta usada en `exportar.php`.

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

// Directamente nombre de archivo desde la tabla "imagenarchivo"
$consulta = "SELECT p.progenid, p.progencod, p.progennom,
        pp.PreProPre1, ia.ia_archivo
        FROM productogenerico p 
        INNER JOIN precioproducto pp
            ON p.progenid = pp.proid
        LEFT JOIN imagenarchivo ia
            ON p.progenid = ia.ia_perid";

$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
$listado = array();

// Asegúrate que es la misma carpeta que usaste al exportar las imágenes
$ruta = 'http://192.168.43.3/WS/img2/';

while($fila  =$resultado->fetch_array()) {
    $producto["progennom"] = $fila['progennom'];
    $producto["PreProPre1"] = $fila['PreProPre1'];
    $producto["progencod"] = $fila['progencod'];

    if($fila['ia_archivo']) {
        // Ya se generó imagen para este producto
        // Solo ruta y nombre del archivo, no el contenido
        $producto["ImaAsoIma"] = $ruta . $fila['ia_archivo'];
    } else {
        // Todavía no se ha generado una imagen
        // Deberías mostrar una por defecto
        $producto['ImaAsoIma'] = 'ruta/imagen-por-defecto.extension';
    }
    $listado[] = $producto;
}

echo json_encode($listado);
$resultado->close();
```

No sé cómo estás manejando el dato al recibirlo en *Javascript*, pero solo debes generar la etiqueta `<img>` y asignar origen; supongo que quedará algo como:

```
let imagen = `<img src="${variableDeFila.ImaAsoIma}">`
```

Comment: Yo no estoy usando Javascript, esta app la estoy haciendo en Android, (Java)  si quieres puedo editar mi pregunta y puedo añadir mi código en Java para que veas cómo recibo el dato

Comment: @StephiRM, sí edita la pregunta, para ver cómo estás creando y mostrando la imagen. Por cierto, creo que puedes eliminar la parte donde exportas los archivos.

Comment: Ya quedó editada la pregunta de arriba

Comment: Y otra cosa, yo en el código de android, tengo hecho la parte de que si no tiene imagen el producto, que muestre una por defecto, pero el problema es que no me la muestra la imagen por defecto

Comment: Y por cierto, la parte que debo mostrar la imagen por defecto, en caso de que el producto no tenga imagen, no me funciona, porque no me aparece dicha imagen por defecto. Cabe aclarar que agregué esta linea:  $producto['ImaAsoIma'] = '/default/noimage.png'; pero no funciona